# Certain CSS Loading Differently Per Screen Resolution

Tags: html, css

I already have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in my HTML files and 99% does load smoothly and correctly on different devices. However, a certain DIV (which contains shape rendering) loads wrongly on smaller/large resolutions.

[iPhone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSb0x.png)

As you can see from this image, there is a gap between the waves and the following div. However, this only shows the gap on smaller devices.

From this image below, is how I want it to look regardless of resolution size.

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqiVd.png)

I have a CSS file for the waves.

```css
.inner-header {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.flex { /*Flexbox for containers*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.waves {
  width: 100%;
  height:15vh;
  margin-bottom:-7px; /*Fix for safari gap*/
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:150px;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  height:20vh;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Animation */

.parallax > use {
  animation: move-forever 25s cubic-bezier(.55,.5,.45,.5)     infinite;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 13s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}
@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(-90px,0,0);
  }
  100% { 
    transform: translate3d(85px,0,0);
  }
}
/*Shrinking for mobile*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .waves {
    height:auto;
    min-height:auto;
  }
  .content {
    height:30vh;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size:24px;
  }
}
```

Here is my DIV which generates waves:

```html
<div>
  <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 12 70 42" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto">
    <defs>
      <path id="gentle-wave" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"></path>
    </defs>
    <g class="parallax">
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="7" fill="#fff"></use>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

My Bootstrap CSS Is also included.
[Bootstrap Code](https://pastebin.com/ebG5kJ35)

Comment: `@itsalexlol` You need to define it where to be positioned at. Also put html code so it will easy for define which that position use for that particular DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `.waves` to `position: absolute;` but not told it where to be positioned at. Include `bottom: 0;` to your style declarations so that it looks like the following:

```css
.waves {
  width: 100%;
  height:15vh;
  margin-bottom:-7px; /*Fix for safari gap*/
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:150px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

That will set the position of `.waves` to the bottom of the [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_Block), you haven't included the page HTML in your question but I'm assuming it will be the parent or close ancestor.

> The size and position of an element are often impacted by its **containing block**. Most often, the containing block is the content area of an element's nearest block-level ancestor, but this is not always the case.

You can read more MDN about [Layout and the containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_Block) and CSS [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).